# Sharepoint 2010: Editing calendar item description is stuck in HTML

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Just inherited the Sharepoint admin role (yay) and am fumbling around but figuring it out.

I created a site with nothing but a Calendar webpart. People have made entries, but, when I go to edit those entries, the description field only shows HTML which is terrible for the userbase. Is there any way around this?

Comment: What browser are you using? Rich text editors are only supported in IE for SharePoint 2010. Otherwise the rich text field will render as a plain textarea with the html displayed.

Comment: I submit it as the answer then, can you mark it as the answer? Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich text editors are only supported in IE for SharePoint 2010. Otherwise the rich text field will render as a plain textarea with the html displayed.